# What is the purpose a 1,0 or 0,1 loop at the end of the language DFA?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, automata, finite-state-machine

Here is a finite-state automata without output:

[Language recognition automata without output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S66ig.png)

In finite-state machine with output, I understand that the *1,0* or 0,1 would give an output of *0* if input is *1* and the opposite.

However, what I don't understand is that in this finite-state automata without an output, what purpose does the *1,0* serve?

Why don't they just write a *0* on the loop instead?

What would happen if the input at *s1* is *1* if there is no where to go from the state if input is *1*?

Comment: There has to be a transition for each of the inputs. The loop indicates that the DFA remains in its current state on the input(s) that label the loop.